# Unexpected Token: Method Build Process

Tags: meteor, methods, babeljs

A strange error is occurring. It seems to be occurring during the Method transpilation process. The method / JS transpilation process seems to be pretty under documented. Any insights into these errors would be helpful. Have been attempting to fix them for a long time.

The error is displaying as such:

```
/Users/WreadWrkrIron/WreadWrkr/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app/lib/methods.js:1
W20160311-20:55:07.625(-8)? (STDERR) (function(Npm, Assets){(function()    {getProfileFollowing (userId) {
W20160311-20:55:07.625(-8)? (STDERR)                                                                     ^
W20160311-20:55:07.627(-8)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
W20160311-20:55:07.628(-8)? (STDERR)     at     /Users/WreadWrkrIron/WreadWrkr/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:241:3    0
W20160311-20:55:07.628(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160311-20:55:07.628(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach     (/Users/AriKamin/.meteor/packages/meteor-    tool/.1.1.10.e4z2zr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-    os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160311-20:55:07.628(-8)? (STDERR)     at     /Users/WreadWrkrIron/WreadWrkr/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

And the original code is such:

```
(function(){getProfileFollowing (userId) {
  return Meteor.users.find({
    'profile.following': Meteor.userId()
  });
},

getUploadedFile (imgId) {
  if (!imgId) {
    return null;
  }
  return UploadedFiles.findOne({
    _id: imgId
  });
},

getAllChats (userId, sortInt) {
  return Chats.find({
    'users':userId
  }, {
    sort: {
      dateCreated: sortInt
    }
  });
},

}).call(this);

//# sourceMappingURL=methods.js.map
```

Comment: I don't think `getProfileFollowing (userId) {` is what a function declaration looks like. Why is the `function` keyword is missing?

Comment: ES2015 fam. there's that

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435209/meteor-up-deploy-failed-but-app-runs-fine-in-development).